# data() not working in R . (version 3.0.2)

Tags: r, dataset

I got a very trivial but a very frustrating problem. The problem is, I want to load data from the packages I have already installed in **R**. This is what I am doing :

1. Open **R**
2. then I would type `data()` to see what data sets are available.
3. Let's see I want to load CO2 data set from the package "datasets"
4. But when I type `data(CO2)` in the console, nothing happens.

Even `co2 <- data(CO2)` doesn't seems to be working. I also tried loading datasets using `library(datasets)` but nothing seems to be working. Please Help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data() loads the dataset into the global environment if not already loaded.
Just type:

```
CO2
```

to access the dataset.
For CO2, you do not even have to use data(CO2).

Comment: Got it!! :) I was about to throw my computer into the ocean.